# Scroll bar covers last row of JList with VERTICAL_WRAP

Tags: java, swing, scroll, jlist

I want to layout a `JList` on one line horizontally, and have it scroll only horizontally. I've found `list.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL_WRAP);` which works well if there are few enough items. However, when the list needs to scroll, the scrollbar covers the last (and only) row of the list, so you can't see it at all. How can I prevent this?

My test code:

```
JList<String> list = new JList<>("TIVFBJPAVUOHCVINPNYLMSMNNDUSHVSWUYUSNZXTYTXJMJPTISAVVYHOPBFIAXSUUQYYPVGAKEEWOTRCBWQWRXQTYJLCTTHTXPMZWDLQRRUZJSVWDMLYNRUDZXRTEJWAZUOBQCWNCYEPVCPXVWOGVZPOEKPWZZFDGZZGXPBFZQQVKFIXCYFTHRPJJMOYISEUCUTJGZQI".split("[A-D]"));
list.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL_WRAP);
list.setVisibleRowCount(1);
frame.add(new JScrollPane(list), BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

The result:

[image: List]

Comment: The scrollbar may not be getting included in the preferredSize calculations (as the `JScrollPane` will compensate for in other ways). Consider using a different layout manager

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Force the scroll pane to include the horizontal scrollbar in its size calculation:

```
JList<String> list = new JList<String>( ... );
list.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL_WRAP);
list.setVisibleRowCount(1);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( list );
scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
frame.add( scrollPane );
```

Comment: Can't believe I didn't think of this before. Thanks.